# legendre Polynomial

Tags: integration, polynomials

Find:

$\int_{-1}^1 P_5(x)+P^2_4(x)\ dx$

my answer:
$\int_{-1}^1 P_5(x) \ dx +\int_{-1}^1 P^2_4(x)\ dx$

$\int_{-1}^1 P_5(x) \ dx$ + $2\over2(4)+1$

$\int_{-1}^1 P_5(x) \ dx$ + $2\over9$

but what about $\int_{-1}^1 P_5(x)$ how can I Calculate it ?
I think:
$P_5(x)$ =$ 1\over 8$$(63x^5-70x^3+15x)$

$ \int_{-1}^1 P_5(x)$=$1\over8$ $\int_{-1}^1 (63x^5-70x^3+15x) \ dx $

$ \int_{-1}^1 P_5(x)$=$1\over8$ ($63\over6$ $x^6$-$70\over4$$x^4$+$15\over2$$x^2$)

true?

Comment: You just have to exploit $$\int_{-1}^{1} P_n(x)\,P_m(x)\,dx = \frac{2\cdot \delta(n,m)}{2n+1}.$$

Comment: $$\int_{-1}^{1}P_5(x)\,dx = \int_{-1}^{1} P_0(x)\cdot P_5(x)\,dx = \color{red}{0}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um... There is tremendous ambiguity in this question. Is that $P_5(x)+P_4^2(x)$ or $P_5(x)\cdot P_4^2(x)$? And is that the square of the fourth degree Legendre Polynomial $\left(P_4(x)\right)^2$ or the second degree associated Legendre polynomial $P_4^2(x)$? Assuming multiplication, we get zero in either case because making the substitution $y=-x$,
$$\int_{-1}^1P_5(x)\cdot P_4^2(x)dx=\int_1^{-1}P_5(-y)\cdot P_4^2(-y)(-dy)=\int_{-1}^1\left(-P_5(y)\right)\cdot P_4^2(y)dy=0$$
Because zero is the only real number which is its own additive inverse.

Comment: It is $(P_4(x))^2$, Thank you so much.

Comment: But the other question was whether it is $P_5(x)+\left(P_4(x)\right)^2$ or $P_5(x)\cdot\left(P_4(x)\right)^2$.

Comment: Oh Sorry, it is $P_5(x)+(P_4(x))^2$.

Comment: OK. Then the answer is $$\int_{-1}^1\left(P_5(x)+\left(P_4(x)\right)^2\right)dx=\int_{-1}^1P_0(x)\cdot P_5(x)dx+\int_{-1}^1\left(P_4(x)\right)^2dx=0+\frac2{2\cdot4+1}=\frac29$$ It's important to have those parentheses around the integrand to avoid ambiguity.